# Is there a way in Flutter, to detect whether my Application is added to the Power Saving Mode / Ultra Power Saving Mode in Android?

Tags: flutter, android-gps

We are developing a GPS live tracking application for a company through Flutter.

1. We understand that even if added to run as a background service, Chinese Roms, kill the applications when added to the battery saver mode.
2. If we can detect if our app is added under the power saving / Ultra Power Saving mode in an application, we can denote / display to the admin of the company , so then they can ask the particular user to remove his app from the power saving mode.
3. Can someone suggest which plugin / methodology to detect if our app is added under the power saving mode or not ?

We tried the following , but dosnt seem to display properly.

**https://pub.dev/packages/disable_battery_optimization/example**

**https://www.flutterant.com/how-to-check-battery-level-and-state-in-flutter**/

**https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info**